# VB6 - View Code will not display code

Tags: vb6

This is probably a really dumb question but i'll ask anyway.
I was wondering if there was any reason as to why a form wouldn't display its code when i click "view code" from the right click context menu in vb6?
It was working awhile ago so i'm kind of stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Is it displaying in your taskbar? (maybe the window is off-screen)

Answer (score 4):

If forms are still not visible, try Window -> Cascade - This was the way I goit my forms visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is being displayed under something else.  Check under the Window menu.  Do you see it there?

Answer (score 0):

Does the form display if you right click and select 'View Object'? If so, try double clicking on the form - that should display the source. You might also check the permissions to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since it's the first link retuned by a Google search, answering here may help many people.

Like someone else said, Window/Cascade does the trick, but with time it becomes annoying.

I have the same problem on my laptop with an external display.  Closing the laptop cover (thus going back to only one display) fixes the issue.

An alternate way is to display the VB6 IDE on the main display (your main display is the one with icons on the bottom right corner).  You can set your main display under System Preferences/Displays.  There's a checkbox called "make this one the main display", it does not need to be your monitor #1.

Problem does not seem to occur if you have 2 displays side-by-side.  Also, the fact that my laptop's resolution is not the same as the external display's resolution may cause the issue.

After taking these steps, you may have to restart the VB6 IDE to fix the issue.